# Input from user not displaying on server side page properly after running query

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Currently I have a form where the user picks a movie and it's value is the movieID

```html
<form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080">
  <div id="radio-section">
    <input type="radio" id="wake" name="movie" value="954">
    <label for="wake">Wake Jaws</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="tomato" name="movie" value="894">
    <label for="tomato">Tomato Hellfighters</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="west" name="movie" value="969">
    <label for="west">West Lion</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="edge" name="movie" value="272">
    <label for="edge">Edge Kissing</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="lolita" name="movie" value="528">
    <label for="lolita">Lolita World</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="dancing" name="movie" value="206">
    <label for="dancing">Dancing Fever</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="random" name="movie" value="random">
    <label for="random">Show me a random movie!</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The input gets pulled and then used within a query string that pulls the movie based of the ID user input and then displays back the movie title and description through node.js

```js
let http = require("http");
let mysql = require("mysql");
const PORT = 8080;
let output = '';
let con;
let count = 0;

initializeDB();
let httpServer = http.createServer(processServerRequest);

httpServer.listen(PORT);

function processServerRequest(request, response){

    grabInput(request);

    console.log(`${output} recieved`);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    response.write('Here is the information you were looking for');
    response.write(output);
    response.end();
} //end of processServerRequest fucntion 

function grabInput(request){
    let base = "http://" + request.headers["host"];
    let url = new URL(request.url, base);

    console.log('Grabbing results...');

    let movieID = url.searchParams.get("movie");
    
    if (movieID == 'random'){
        movieID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
    }

    let sqlquery = `select title, description from film where film_id = ${movieID};`
    con.query(sqlquery, processResult);
}

function processResult(err, result){
    if (err){
        console.log("Error detected.");
        throw err;
    } //end of if statement
    else{
        console.log(`page opened ${count} times`)
        count++;
        console.log(`There were ${result.length} rows returned`);
        result.forEach(printMovie);
    } // end of else statement
} //end of processResult function 

function printMovie(record){
    console.log(`${record.title} ${record.description}`);
    output=`<p><strong>${record.title}</strong><br><br>${record.description}</p>`;
}
```

For some reason, instead of just displaying the correct output, it initially does not have the movie title and description after I press submit. When I go back to the form page and select another movie and press select again, it then displays the movie information for the one I selected before.

example:

1. I select Jaws and press submit
2. nothing displays
3. I go back select Spiderman and press submit
4. Jaw movie information displays

[node.js output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoFh9.jpg)

It looks like my processResult function runs twice, grabbing the correct output the first time, but then running again and assigning output to an empty string. How can I make it so it displays the proper movie information?